# Can't figure this out. asp.net c# to sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, asp-classic

SqlException was unhandled by user code

> Incorrect syntax near 'Department'.

How to solve something like this guys?

Here is my codes in visual studio asp.net connecting to sql server

```
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection();
        connect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=JMSANTOS-PC;Initial Catalog='Purchasing Department';Integrated Security=True"; 
        connect.Open();

        SqlCommand statement = new SqlCommand();
        statement.Connection = connect;
        statement.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Purchasing Department VALUES" + 
            "('" + Username.Text + 
            "', '" + Password.Text + 
            "', '" + LastName.Text + 
            "', '" + FirstName.Text + 
            "', '" + Address.Text + 
            "', '" + Contactno.Text + "')";

        statement.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Response.Redirect("RegComplete.aspx");
```

Comment: You need to post some code here. No one can diagnose it based on this information only.

Comment: Could you please show your relevant code?

Comment: You solve it with correct code.Just as helpful as your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You have: `Initial Catalog='Purchasing Department'`.
Is `Purchasing Department` a DB or a table?
You should insert into tables not into DBs.

2)
Try also `INSERT INTO [Purchasing Department] VALUES`

3) Even better: check the `INSERT` statement syntax and then fix your code.

4) `INSERT INTO [Register] ([Username], [Password] , [LastName], [FirstName], [Address], [ContactNO]) VALUES (list_column_values)`

5) Only change this part of your code:

`statement.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Register] ([Username], [Password] , [LastName], [FirstName], [Address], [ContactNO]) VALUES "`

```
    statement.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Register] ([Username], [Password] , [LastName], [FirstName], [Address], [ContactNO]) VALUES " + 
        "('" + Username.Text + 
        "', '" + Password.Text + 
        "', '" + LastName.Text + 
        "', '" + FirstName.Text + 
        "', '" + Address.Text + 
        "', '" + Contactno.Text + "')";
```

Comment: Still got the error.. invalid object name 'Purchasing Department'.

Comment: Because it's messed up all the way. See my updated answer.

Comment: Still same dude. Look at my codes in my connectionstring part. And yes Purchasing Department is my DB.

Comment: No, see 4) specifically, dude. Your SQL statement from `VALUES` on is OK. You need to fix the part before the `VALUES`.

Comment: My table is dbo.Register and my column name are Username, Password, LastName, FirstName, Address and ContactNO.

< INSERT INTO [Register] (<Username>) Values () what next?

Comment: OK, see answer now. Don't change anything after `VALUES` just the part before it.

Comment: What should i put in list_colum_values ?

Comment: Dude, you already have the values thing. See 5). Change only this and nothing more.

Comment: `statement.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Register] ([Username], [Password] , [LastName], [FirstName], [Address], [ContactNO]) VALUES "` That's all you need changed.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Change your</strike>

```
INSERT INTO Purchasing Department
```

to

```
INSERT INTO Purchasing (Department)
```

Sounds like your table name is `Purchasing` and your column name is `Department` (I assume). And you should use your column name in parentheses.

### But wait a second..

You are using one column name but you try to insert 6 values. If your table has 6 column total, you don't need to use column name.

> Purchasing Department is my database and my table in SQL is
>   dbo.Register.

Ok. Now make sense more but still there are somethings unclear. First of all, your `INSERT` syntax is wrong. Here [`INSERT` syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

```
INSERT [ INTO] 
    { table_name WITH ( < table_hint_limited > [ ...n ] ) 
        | view_name 
        | rowset_function_limited 
    } 

    {    [ ( column_list ) ] 
        { VALUES 
            ( { DEFAULT | NULL | expression } [ ,...n] ) 
            | derived_table 
            | execute_statement 
        } 
    }
```

As you can see, you need to use **table name** instead of your **database name**.

And always use [*parameterized queries*](http://codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [*SQL Injection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

For example;

```
using(SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JMSANTOS-PC;Initial Catalog='Purchasing Department';Integrated Security=True"))
{
   using(SqlCommand statement = new SqlCommand())
   {
      statement.Connection = connect;
      statement.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Register
                               VALUES (@user, @pass, @last, @first, @address, @contact)";
      statement.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", Username.Text);
      statement.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", Password.Text);
      statement.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", LastName.Text);
      statement.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", FirstName.Text);
      statement.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", Address.Text);
      statement.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", Contactno.Text);
      connect.Open();
      statement.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

Comment: Changed it already but the 'Purchasing' now got the same problem.

Comment: @user3104439 What are `Purchasing` and `Department` exatly?

Comment: Purchasing Department is my database and my table in SQL is dbo.Register.

Comment: Sorry but i'm just new in connecting this thing. I cant understand the codes. :(

Comment: @user3104439 before using ado.net find some tutorial and learn basic SQL syntax

Comment: @user3104439 Updated my answer. But please, read a book first..